# I need to create two Views (UICollectionView & UIScrollView) one upon another, on single page with scrolling,

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, xib

I have to create two views in one view controller, where one is UICollectionView with horizontal scrolling, and another is UIScrollView with only vertical scrolling.
So the problem is UIScrollview is above the UICollectionView, due to which I am unable to scroll collection view. I have used Swipe Gesture to handle the collection view

Please check the screenshot I have attached.

I am using XIB to create the UI.

Please help to make it in proper and accurate way. Thanks in Advance.
[image]